# Angular7: Issue with interceptor not getting hit, unable to figure out

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ui-router

May sound trivial, but, I have logic at backend to validate whether the user falls in the white listed user or not, based on which I auth user to proceed. Idea is to move user to 403 page if it do not fall in list. This is a project requirement and cant use builtin authguard etc concept here.

Here is the backend code, which works fine. It directly post to index page, when the user is not auth.

```
import * as express from 'express';

let router = express.Router();
router.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
let userName = userService.getUser(req);
if(req.originalUrl.indexOf('') !== -1 && userService.validateUser(userName) === false){
    console.log('[WARN] Not authorized access by user : '+ userName);
    return res.status(403).send("Authorization failure: Contact the EIS team to get access to this site.");
}}
```

Now I have written an app-interceptor-service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpResponseBase } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    // constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    //         console.log('construcot AppInterceptorService');
    // }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('********** coming*********');
      return next.handle(req).do(event => {
          console.log('********** coming');
        if (event instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
          const response = event as HttpResponseBase;
          if (response.status === 403) {
            window.location.href = 'https://my-403-page.com';
            return next.handle(req);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

My app.module.ts includes interceptor

```
providers: [
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AppInterceptorService,
  multi: true
}
],
```

also imported HTTPClientModule in app.module.ts,

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'
```

Optional info --> In app.component.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Upgrade Service Admin UI'

public user: User
public serviceVersion: ServiceVersion
private _userSub$: Subscription
private _serviceVersionSub$: Subscription

constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('appcomponent loading')
  this._serviceVersionSub$ = this._http.get('version')
.subscribe(data => {
  this.serviceVersion = data as ServiceVersion
  this._cdr.markForCheck()
})
this._userSub$ = this._http.get('user')
.subscribe(data => {
  this.user = data as User
  this._cdr.markForCheck()
})
```

I am not able figure out what is causing interceptor not getting detected. New to angular, appreciate you for educating me.

Comment: So you are not even getting '********** coming*********' in the log?

Comment: no, m not getting ********** coming********* trace.

Comment: do you have `imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],` in **@NgModule**?

Comment: Also, instead of using `HttpResponseBase` use `HttpResponse`.

Comment: yes: imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]